# If one of the leading second order principal minor of a Hessian matrix is negative can I claim that the matrix is negative semi-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, hessian-matrix

I am checking for Sylvester's criterion. If one principal minor is negative does it mean the Hessian is negative semi-definite?

Comment: Not necessarily.  How big is the matrix?  What other information do we have?

Comment: Are you perhaps conflating "negative semi-definite" with "not positive semidefinite"? Many (symmetric) matrices are not semidefinite at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not mean that the matrix is negative semidefinite. In order to show that the matrix is negative semidefinite, you should show that all its principal minors are nonpositive.